# Adding div inside another div without separate scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have project, where I need to add popup form. Here is my project structure.

```
<body>
   <div class="header">ART Compiler Explorer </div>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="box1">

                <div id="inside" >
                        <label for="input-file" class="custom-file-upload">Select Java File</label>
                        <select class="tab" name="android" id="android">  </select>
                </div>
                <textarea id="editor" name="field1"><?php if(isset($_POST['field1'])){echo htmlentities ($_POST['field1']);}?>
                </textarea>
         </div>
        <div class="box1 box2">
                <div id="second" >
                        <select class="tabb" name="launguage" id="launguage" onchange='this.form.submit()' > </select>
                        <button type ="button" class="btn"  onclick='this.form.submit()'>Refresh</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to add popup form under `div id="inside"`
which have code structure like:

```
<button class="add" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Add ToolChain</button>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
    </div>
    <div class="container_form">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is The popup does not come in fully as in above link, instead it get hidden by first half text editor (see the blue colour line, which get shifted by left).

It seems popup `div id "id01"`make seperate space inside the `div id ="inside"`, so not coming properly. Please suggest me how to tackle this problem as I have to add popup form under `div id="inside"`, but this pop up form contain itself another `div` which make separate space. 
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: include your css also

Comment: Which of your fiddles is supposed to reproduce what your last screenshot shows now? I can’t see that in any of them.

Comment: @Hammadtariq, I have included the css in the link, see the jsfiddle link which shows each step of css code . Thanks!

Comment: @04FS, fiddles is not showing may be text area we need to do stratch manually. And its just sample code I produced to get the overall flow. Also in fiddles i have given `.add` to float right, but not showing properly

Comment: Might be browser specific - as @04FS asserts, the last fiddle with the dialog does not produce the screenshot you've provided - it puts a modal dialog in the middle of the page as expected

Comment: @04FS, In my project I have created textarea editor in left box by code mirror, which in fiddles I do not able to show

Comment: your last screenshot could not present in any JS fiddle

Comment: @Hammadtariq, yes might the php code i did not included to get the same output as in my real project

Comment: can you explain in simple words what actually what you want

Comment: @Hammadtariq, I want to add a popup under the div "inside" ( i.e. where all button and selection menu placed) so that when user click the button (here Add Toolchain) a popup form come for user entry.

Comment: @Hammadtariq, The popup form detail code , I have created under the link https://jsfiddle.net/zu289hxL/

Comment: @Hammadtariq, which I want to add to the exiting project under the `div id="inside"` , the detail code found for exiting sample project from this link: https://jsfiddle.net/v3udmb51/

Comment: you want your popup is open only in textarea section right?

Comment: @Hammadtariq, anywhere in the screen, but the background get dim while opening the popup. I prefer to open the popup in center

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uqzx7w0v/1/    i hope you want this maybe

Comment: @Hammadtariq, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: @Hammadtariq, the text area is hiding the popup form

Comment: but its working for me ok you can use  `z-index:4; ` on your popup also increase `z-index` value

Comment: can i post it as an answer

Comment: @Hammadtariq, Yes sure. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup is not coming over the textarea because of `z-index`, add `z-index:4` to your popup modal so that it can come on top of the textarea.

```
.modal {
    z-index:4
 }
```